# How to get a set of numbers between 10^0 and 10^-3

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have a list of numbers between 0 and -3 which I got using...

`InfectProbs=np.arange(0, (-3-(3/11)), -(3/11)).tolist()`

However, I need to get this list of numbers to become 10^(i) where i is a number in the InfectProbs list.
I attempted to do..

`InfectProbs=(10^(np.arange(0, (-3-(3/11)), -(3/11)))).tolist()`

But got the error message of...

*ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''*

So, how do I get my desired output?

Comment: `**` is the power operator...

Comment: `^` is the xor operator

Comment: Sounds like you simply want `np.logspace(0, -3, -12)`. (You might also be interested in [`np.geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html).)

Answer (score 0):

use [np.power](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html)

```py
np.power(10, InfectProbs)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, in python you need to use ** for powers, not ^. So your code should be:
`InfectProbs=(10**(np.arange(0, (-3-(3/11)), -(3/11)))).tolist()`

^ is the bitwise xor operator so this is where your error comes from (bitwise xor doesn't work for floats)